# nginx is taking a long time to show changes to files

Tags: nginx

When I make edits to a file on my nginx server it some times (not always), takes 3-10 seconds before that change will show.  (Note I'm running CakePHP 3.2, on an EC2 micro instance, if that makes any difference).

For example, I'll add `debug('hello'); exit;` to a page I'm looking at in the browser. Then I'll save it, and refresh.  Sometimes that change will show up immediately.  Sometimes, I'll need to refresh up to 20 times before the change shows. Anyone know how to make all changes show up immediately, so that I'm not sitting here wondering if I didn't save or if I'm working in the wrong file, or if my change did anything for 10 seconds after every save.

I've tried turning off cache by adding

```
sendfile  off;
```

to the conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question turned out to be an issue with PHP 5.5 OPcaching being on by default when installed via a bitnami AMI on AWS.  I re-asked the question correctly, and answered it here : [php not showing changes to files consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617253/php-not-showing-changes-to-files-consistently/35617254#35617254)