# php not showing changes to files consistently

Tags: php, php-5.5, opcache

I am making changes to php files and they are not showing -- sometimes.   Sometimes they will show immediately.  Sometimes I have to wait a few minutes.  I've gone through and turned off all the cache that I could think to turn off. The problem is inconsistent and tough to duplicate consistently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I spent quite awhile doing trials to consistently reproduce the behavior. I had to let the server sit without refresh any page for a few minutes.  Then if I change the file before I refresh the page, the change show immediately and all subsequent changes show immediately.  If I refresh the page first, then make a change to the file, then no subsequent changes show until I refresh 10-20 times, or so.

BTW, html files show all updates regardless, so it was a php issue.

Before finding the answer, I tried...

- turning off nginx cache
- setting nginx conf to `sendfile off;`
- setting nginx conf to `expires off;`

... none of these work.  I then found that it was in fact OPcache. I fixed the issue by changing the php.ini file to this (and restarting all services)

`opcache.enable=0`

Comment: FYI another way to fix this, but leave OPcache on is to change opcache.revalidate_freq to 0 instead.  `OPcache.revalidate_freq=0`

Answer (score 1):

My problem regarding this issue was solved by referring to this link

:[Nginx Server “caches” PHP. Updated Page does not Reload](https://serverfault.com/a/828584/588645)

by :

```
service php-fpm restart # most centos
service php7-php-fpm restart # centos and remi php7
service php7.0-fpm restart # ubuntu
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try the below meta tag in your header?

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try hitting ctrl+shift+R for hard reload.
Your welcome.

Comment: Arrogant and wrong, what a combination.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).